# SQL Server DISTINCT pagination with ROW_NUMBER() not distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination, distinct

Ok, so basically my `DISTINCT` is rendered useless by using `ROW_NUMBER()`, I need to avoid this as it's causing duplicate results (apart from a unique num of course!)

So what I'm looking for is a query that'll work the same but not have duplicate rows because num is unique:

```
WITH t AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS num 
   FROM Original_Import 
   LEFT JOIN eqcas.dbo.BASE_PROXY_VIEW_WITHTARGET ON ADName = Targetuser
   WHERE (BaseProxy = 'agmc' OR ADName = 'agmc')
      AND (Commited IS NULL OR Commited = 0)
)
SELECT DISTINCT ID, num, ADName, Description_User, Description_Amex, Amount, Date
FROM t 
WHERE (t.BaseProxy = 'agmc' OR t.ADName = 'agmc') 
   AND num BETWEEN 0 AND 20
   AND (Commited IS NULL OR Commited = 0)
ORDER BY Date
```

It's probably fairly trivial to fix, but seeing as I'm not a SQL Server guy I'm not used to these inner queries etc..

**Update: yes, num is used for paging.**

Comment: Any idea on the syntax, and where that'd go? Remember I don't know MSSQL!

Comment: see below and try. Now I'm thinknig I didn't understand you quite right. you need rows to be numbered in right way, so your CTE does not work as expected?

Comment: Is the `BETWEEN 0 AND 20` static, or is this used for paging results?

Comment: All I can think to do is execute a sub query on the with T as doing the distinct first and then add row number AFTER the distinct has processed... I'd work on the syntax but i'm not near SQL atm...  but that seems like it would be slow....

Comment: Slowness isn't a concern :) That sounds like the right solution though. Can anyone provide syntax? I struggle with inner queries as I come from a mysql background and never use them.

Comment: You could have also used `DENSE_RANK` which would have given you the same "row number" for the same date.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems like I'm two years late with my recent blog post about [`ROW_NUMBER()` being to `SELECT` what `DENSE_RANK()` is to `SELECT DISTINCT`](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/09/sql-trick-row_number-is-to-select-what-dense_rank-is-to-select-distinct/). Your CTE would have to be replaced by this:

```
WITH t AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Date, ...) AS num 
   FROM Original_Import 
   LEFT JOIN eqcas.dbo.BASE_PROXY_VIEW_WITHTARGET ON ADName = Targetuser
   WHERE (BaseProxy = 'agmc' OR ADName = 'agmc')
      AND (Commited IS NULL OR Commited = 0)
)
SELECT ...
```

In the above query, the `DENSE_RANK()`'s `ORDER BY` clause will need to list all columns from `Original_Import` and from `BASE_PROXY_VIEW_WITH_TARGET`, to reproduce the same ordering as the `DISTINCT` keyword. That will assign exactly one rank per duplicate record set, such that `DISTINCT` will work again.

In the [referenced blog post](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/09/sql-trick-row_number-is-to-select-what-dense_rank-is-to-select-distinct/), I have also included a link to a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b4124/7) illustrating this in a more trivial example.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  v, 
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (w) row_number
FROM t
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY v)
ORDER BY v, row_number
```

[An explanation why `DISTINCT` removes duplicate rows *after* window functions having been calculated can be found in this post here](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/).

Comment: You may have been two years late with the answer, but I'm another year late having it be useful to me. Thanks a bunch! ;)

Comment: Hi @LukasEder, thank you for the great post!, how would you incorporate something such as `COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY 1)` with the `DENSE_RANK`?

Comment: @epoch: Not quite sure what you mean. You want to count the distinct records? I.e. the records that are left over after removing duplicates? (this would possibly best answered in a new stack overflow question)

Comment: @LukasEder, thanks for the reply lukas, I solved it by asking a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969508/sql-total-row-count-dense-rank-distinct :)

Comment: several years late but I have changed this to the accepted answer. Thanks to all those who contributed. I have changed employers several times since then lol.

Answer (score 5):

limited confidence on this as I can't test or even compile  but this is the general gist of what I was thinking...

```
WITH t AS
(
   SELECT [insert your fields here], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS num 
   FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT *[insert your fields here]
     FROM Original_Import 
     LEFT JOIN eqcas.dbo.BASE_PROXY_VIEW_WITHTARGET ON ADName = Targetuser
     WHERE (BaseProxy = 'agmc' OR ADName = 'agmc')
      AND (Commited IS NULL OR Commited = 0)) as X
)
SELECT DISTINCT ID, num, ADName, Description_User, Description_Amex, Amount, Date
FROM t 
WHERE (t.BaseProxy = 'agmc' OR t.ADName = 'agmc') 
   AND num BETWEEN 0 AND 20
   AND (Commited IS NULL OR Commited = 0)
ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: Spot on. There may have been easier ways to do this, but I think given the circumstances this is the best answer for several reasons: 1. I understand how it works 2. It works perfectly 3. I have confidence it shouldn't screw up anything else.

Comment: Actually, as a side note the innermost query here doesn't actually return a unique set of results, but by selecting just those I need (like the last query in the query) it worked.

Comment: @JohnHunt: A bit late, but [`DENSE_RANK()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19617806/521799) might've been an appropriate choice, here