# Distinct Pagination with ROW_NUMBER() and Total Count in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, pagination

In Asp.net, I am trying to achieve pagination using following code:

```
String query="SELECT * "+
             "FROM (SELECT Distinct emp_name, emp_address, "+
             "         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY emp_id) AS rownum"+
             "       FROM Employee"+
             "     )as Person "+
             "WHERE rownum>"+ start +" and rownum <="+ end +";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
conn.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Above code does not retrieve `Distinct` rows.
How can I adjust my `query` to get `distinct` **emp_name** and `order by` **emp_id** along with total number of entries in single `ExecuteReader()`?

Currently I am calling `ExecuteReader()` twice first for data and and second for total count.

I followed [SQL Server DISTINCT pagination with ROW_NUMBER() not distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160694/sql-server-distinct-pagination-with-row-number-not-distinct) but was unable to understand how to implement it in my code. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.Format` and raw string (`@`) to avoid concatenation.

```
String query = String.Format(@"
    select emp_name, emp_address, rownum 
    from (
        select
            emp_name, emp_address,
            row_number() over(order by emp_id) as rownum
        from (
            select distinct emp_name, emp_address
            from employee
        ) s
    ) as Person 
    where rownum > {0} and rownum <= {1}
    ;
    select count(*) as total
    from (
        select distinct emp_name, emp_address
        from employee
        where rownum > {0} and rownum <= {1}
    ) s
    ;    
", start, end);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
conn.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

// gets the first data set
while (reader.Read())
{
    ...
}

// gets the second
reader.NextResult();
reader.Read();
int total = (int)reader["total"];
```

Use `NextResult` to read multiple result sets.

Answer (score 1):

Row_Number() will kill your Distinct.  Put the Distinct inside of your sub query and row number over the (outer) result set (after you have a distinct set).

```
String query="SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(ORDER BY emp_id) AS rownum "+
          "FROM (SELECT Distinct emp_name, emp_address, emp_id "+
          "       FROM Employee"+
          "     )as Person "+
          "WHERE rownum>"+ start +" and rownum <="+ end +";
```

Comment: You cannot reference the ROW_NUMBER() column from within the same query level (It needs to be in a sub-query or CTE)