# SQL Total Row Count (DENSE_RANK/DISTINCT)

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, ranking, dense-rank

I am selecting records that may contain duplicates, I need to be able to paginate a distinct result set.

At the moment, I have the following (simplified) query:

```
SELECT pagiWrapper.*  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT alias.id
    , alias.name
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY alias.name ASC) AS 'paginationRowNo'
    , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY 1) AS 'paginationTotalRows' 
        FROM MyTable alias 
        LEFT JOIN MyTableTwo alias2 ON alias2.id = alias.id 
            WHERE ( /* condition */)
) pagiWrapper WHERE pagiWrapper.paginationRowNo > 0 AND pagiWrapper.paginationRowNo <= 15
```

There are 10 records in this result-set, however `DISTINCT` correctly returns 3, and `DENSE_RANK` correctly labels them `1`, `2`, and `3`

My problem is `paginationTotalRows` still returns 10 (the original duplicates-included) result-set count, how can I modify the query so that `paginationTotalRows` returns the correct amount?

Comment: What version of SQL Server is being used please?

Comment: @Used_By_Already, 2005

Comment: I do really suggest row_number() for this, check it out please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the windowing function outside the `select distinct`. I would also suggest you use row_number() instead of dense_rank().

```
SELECT
      pagiWrapper.*
FROM (
            SELECT
                  iq.*
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY iq.name ASC) AS 'paginationRowNo'
                , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1)           AS 'paginationTotalRows'
            FROM (
                  SELECT DISTINCT
                        alias.id
                      , alias.name
                      , alias2.something_I_hope
                  FROM MyTable alias
                        LEFT JOIN MyTableTwo alias2
                                    ON alias2.id = alias.id
                  WHERE (1 = 1 /* condition */)
                  ) iq
      ) pagiWrapper
WHERE pagiWrapper.paginationRowNo > 0
      AND pagiWrapper.paginationRowNo <= 15
```

I recommend `ROW_NUMBER()` for pagination. This function cannot repeat a number within a partition and, if not partitioned it cannot repeat a number at all. `DENSE_RANK()` however can repeat a number within any partition and, if not partitioned can still repeat numbers. For pagination to be utterly predictable you need utterly predictable row numbering, so use `ROW_NUMBER()`. [please]

Comment: Im using DENSE_RANK as ROW_NUMBER does not work with DISTINCT, http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/09/sql-trick-row_number-is-to-select-what-dense_rank-is-to-select-distinct/

Comment: it does if you move it outside the select distinct

Comment: not a problem, dense_rank() has its uses, but not here IMHO

Answer (score 2):

Try to find `MAX(paginationRowNo)` in the top query:

```
 SELECT pagiWrapper.*
      FROM(
           SELECT *, 
                 MAX(paginationRowNo) OVER(PARTITION BY 1) 
                    as 'paginationTotalRows'  
            FROM
             (           
              SELECT DISTINCT alias.id
               , alias.name
               , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY alias.name ASC) AS 'paginationRowNo'
                  FROM MyTable alias 
                  LEFT JOIN MyTableTwo alias2 ON alias2.id = alias.id 
                     WHERE ( /* condition */)
              ) as PW
         ) pagiWrapper 
           WHERE pagiWrapper.paginationRowNo > 0 
                 AND pagiWrapper.paginationRowNo <= 15
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer valex! @t-clausen.dk, I liked your explanation (don't know why you deleted your answer - thank you anyway!).

Comment: @epoch valex's answer was almost the same as mine. So I was not adding much to the answer. I also saw you had enough points to read my answer

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, Thank you in any case! i thought I was lost on this one :)

Comment: @valex, i'm moving more to the other answer as this prevents the pagination from working (I can't get the full result set any more), I appreciate the answer though